# Set of sets (of sets...)

Tags: javascript, set, ecmascript-6

In Python, it is possible to have a set of sets by means of `frozenset`:

```
s, t = frozenset([1]), frozenset([1])
u = {s, t} # u == {frozenset([1])}
```

Now that ECMAScript 6 brings `Set` object, is there any way in JavaScript to have a set containing other sets uniquely, i.e. to discard all the sets but one having the same items?

I'm asking because this doesn't work:

```
var s = new Set([1]), t = new Set([1]);
var u = new Set([s, t]); // u == Set{Set{1}, Set{1}}
```

I understand that `Set` probably hashes the pointers of other sets it includes, that's why the two `{1}` appear distinct. What I'm asking is whether there is a way in JavaScript to achieve Python behavior illustrated above.

Comment: The behaviour is correct. The sets `s` and `t` are different objects, so they should be distinct.

Comment: *"What I'm asking is whether there is a way in JavaScript to achieve Python behavior illustrated above."* No. JavaScript doesn't have a way atm to define object equality.

Comment: @FelixKling If that's really the case, please post your answer bellow, I'll accept it.

Comment: I guess you could create a proxy that traps adding items to the set and skips adding an item if it is deeply equal to an existing member.

Answer (score 2):

That's because in JavaScript values which are objects are considered equal only if they are the same object. For example `{} === {}` evaluates to `false`.

As pointed out by @torazaburo, you could create a proxy for that set that would trap `.add()` calls and skip items that are equal to any of the existing members. You can use [`_.isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) function from lodash library to compare two sets.

```
const firstSet = new Set([1])
     ,secondSet = new Set([1])

const newSet = new Set()

newSet.add = new Proxy(newSet.add, {
  apply: (target, thisArg, [value])=> {
    // Array.from() is required to use Array.prototype.some()
    if (!Array.from(newSet).some(element=> _.isEqual(element, value))) {
      target.call(newSet, value)
    }
    return target
  }
})

newSet.add(firstSet)
newSet.add(secondSet)

console.log(newSet.has(firstSet))  // logs true
console.log(newSet.has(secondSet)) // logs false, because secondSet 
                                   // has not been added, since it's a duplicate
console.log(newSet.size)           // logs 1
```

See [JS Bin demo](https://jsbin.com/mikecol/5/edit?js,console).

Comment: I'm not that well versed in JavaScript but isn't that `apply` run in O(n)? I mean, does this basically iterates over all the already included sets and compares each with `Array.isEqual` in another O(n)? How is it different than using arrays, instead of sets?

Comment: @EcirHana You are right, it's no different than using arrays.